# RapidMinder/R exporting date attributes to R

Tags: r, rapidminer

When exporting my RapidMiner example set to R, dates get mangled:

[image]

The original dates in the RapidMiner example set:

[image]

Apparently, the months get replaced by `00`. I use the "Export Example Set" operator to create the R data set.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works fine here on RapidMiner 5.3 +  R version 2.15.0, although my date format is `%d.%m.%Y` and not `%b %d, %Y` and the output isn't converted to datetime / POSIXct. Maybe you want to experiment with the `Execute Script` operator and try something like `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english"); df$entry_date <- as.Date(df$entry_date, format = "%b %d, %Y")` or `df$entry_date <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$entry_date, format = "%b %d, %Y"))`. What happend, now?

Comment: Both made the date become NaN. That field is supposed to already be a date, not a string, does that make a difference? I created it using the date_parse function from RapidMiner. Interestingly, putting that Script operator in made another attribute come through the Export operator, a string version of the date I used for debugging, but that didn't previously get exported, for whatever reason.

Comment: @lukeA I use a string of the form yyyy/mm/dd and then use as.Date in my plotting script now, that worked. On the way I encountered lots of unexpected behavior, though. Also I am still not sure why the export "RapidMiner date" -> "R date" doesn't work directly.

Comment: Well, it seems the `date_parse*` functions don't return dates but date_times. Maybe there's a bug in the R extension so that it fails to handle them. However, as I said, you could heal it by using `Execute Script` and `df$entry_date <- as.Date(df$entry_date, format = "%b %d, %Y")`.